# Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. on Docker Container

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vite

I made a Docker setup to run my Vue project, but when the container is beginning to run, I got the error in the title.

More details:

```bash
frontend-1  | > frontend@0.0.0 dev
frontend-1  | > vite
frontend-1  |
frontend-1  | /app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:87
frontend-1  |           throw new Error(
frontend-1  |                 ^
frontend-1  |
frontend-1  | Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
frontend-1  |     at requireWithFriendlyError (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:87:9)
frontend-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:96:76)
frontend-1  |     ... 3 lines matching cause stack trace ...
frontend-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
frontend-1  |     at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:359:17)
frontend-1  |     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:308:7)
frontend-1  |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
frontend-1  |     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24) {
frontend-1  |   [cause]: Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu'
frontend-1  |   Require stack:
frontend-1  |   - /app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js
frontend-1  |       at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
frontend-1  |       at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
frontend-1  |       at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
frontend-1  |       at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
frontend-1  |       at requireWithFriendlyError (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:69:10)
frontend-1  |       at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:96:76)
frontend-1  |       at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
frontend-1  |       at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
frontend-1  |       at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
frontend-1  |       at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12) {
frontend-1  |     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
frontend-1  |     requireStack: [ '/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js' ]
frontend-1  |   }
frontend-1  | }
frontend-1  |
frontend-1  | Node.js v21.6.2
Gracefully stopping... (press
```

I tried three different "solutions" so far.

1. Adding that dependency as `optionalDependencies` in the `package.json`:

   ```json
     "optionalDependencies": {
       "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.9.5"
     },
   ```
2. Add `overrides`:

   ```json
     "overrides": {
       "vite": {
         "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
       }
     }
   ```
3. Tried to use different Node version in the Dockerfile.

None of them worked until now, every time I run docker-compose the same error happens.

My frontend project Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE  5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` is inside another directory, of the back end project:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    webquarto:
        container_name: webquarto
        image: webquarto:1.0.2
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html

    db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:12
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: 
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
            POSTGRES_DB: 
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    frontend:
        build:
            context: ../frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5173:5173"
        volumes:
            - ../frontend:/app
            - ../node_modules:/frontend/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - webquarto



volumes:
    pgdata: {}
```

Comment: Most likely due to https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828 - _do_ you see it in the lockfile?

Comment: Is this in the `frontend` container?  The `volumes:` there are hiding absolutely everything you do in the Dockerfile.  If your host system doesn't have that installed in its `node_modules` directory, nothing in the Dockerfile can fix it.